# Exhaust wiring problems in a old house

Tags: electrical, wiring, remodeling, old-work

I'm remodeling a bathroom from 1932, at some point someone put an exhaust fan/light/heater combo in. With all 3 functions on separate switches.

It has 3 stacked switches in a single 1 gang box. The new exhaust is a fan/light combo and I also need to install 2 4" LED flush mount lights, and want everything in the 3 switch, single gang box.

Not really a big problem. Except I only have 1 neutral wire which was on the heater switch, which will end up being the LED lights.

Originally only 2 12/2 cables went to the heater/light/exhaust. One of which used the white & black as 2 separate switch legs (both are hot) one for the fan and one for the light. Which left the second 12/2 normal i.e. black = hot, white = neutral, both cables are grounded originally, all of the neutrals were connected to the neutral from the 2nd 12/2 cable.

My dilemma is that I need all 3 switches. I want the fan & light on separate switches and want the 2 LED lights on the 3rd switch. I only have neutral going to the led lights unless I pigtail the neutral. All of this is on the same breaker circuit.

My question is: Can I use the 1 neutral for everything like the original setup did, since it's all still on the same?

Pictures of connections at the original bathroom  exhaust fan/ light/ heater  unit

[image]
<sup>Click all images to embiggen</sup>
[image]
[image]

Cables as connected (all wires come from  the same stacked 3 single pole light switch):

Cable #2:

- White with black tape = blue
- Black = black
- Bare(ground) = green

Cable #1:

- Black = red
- White = 2x white (neutrals in unit)
- Bare(ground) = green

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MJgV.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxvbU.jpg

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please? Also, is running replacement wiring for the 12/2 pair to the heater/light/exhaust fan an option?

Comment: That "using dual 12/2 as a substitute for 12/4" thing is a Code problem, see NEC 300.3. Currents must be balanced/equal in each cable or conduit.  If you are going to violate that anyway, minimize the adverse effects by making the "heater" hot be the one in the same cable with the neutral.

Comment: That "using dual 12/2 as a substitute for 12/4" thing is a Code problem, see NEC 300.3. Currents must be balanced/equal in each cable or conduit. If you are going to violate that anyway, minimize the adverse effects by making the "heater" hot be the one in the same cable with the neutral. 

– 
That is how it was originally.  I'm not going back with a heater.. I want to do a fan / light combo.   Then add 2 led  wafer style  lights.

Comment: @Threephase. No not really.  The hvac unit is in the way in the attic.  I will come up with something. Most likely  I'll have to figure out how to run new wite.   I'm not excited about  it

Comment: I can tell you that the bathroom  is on 1 breaker.   What someone did was run 2 12/2 with ground romex cables from the switch to the OLD EXHAUST/ LIGHT/ HEATER.. one of the romex 12/2 the black & white wires are "runners"  or  "switch legs"  ( whatever  you want to call them)   then the 2nd  12/2 with ground  romex was ran to the heater (black wire) and neutral ( white wires)   grounds where all ties together  ( 3 grounds total)

Comment: I'm adding 2 small led lights and replacing  the exhaust  with a light/fan  only exhaust .. all together  the new stuff  should  draw less power than the old unit.  Since it's all on one breaker why can't I just pigtail the one neutral .  I'll get pics  soon anyway

Comment: Since your familiarity with electrical wiring terms is currently limited, it might help to draw up a schematic of how the wiring is currently, and how you envision it for your project. This way, the experts here can look at what you're thinking and use the proper terms so you can learn them, too.

Comment: I can do that.   May I ask what terms are unclear?  I was/am trying  to use accepted terminology

Comment: @Brad I think you are talking about "traveler" wires when you say "runners" or "switch legs". A wiring diagram as Freeman asked for would help immensely.

Comment: "wires" refers to a single conductor that typically has an insulating jacket. When these are bundled it's referred to as a "cable" - I fixed this in the question.

Comment: I apologize for the mistake.. yes by  "runners" & "switch leg" I do mean TRAVLERS..  I do mean "cable" when I say "wire". Again  I apologize.  I assumed everyone  would understand  given the context clues.   I got pictures  of the switch box ( hope thats right terminology) I'll draw a diagram  as well.

Comment: Please see the [formatting guide](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for details on uploading images directly in your question. Links to imgur.com rather than our i.stack.imgur.com will eventually expire making this question less useful in the future.